# Get duplicate Realtime Database Firebase results in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to build realtime chat through Realtime Database Firebase and Xamarin. However there is a problem like this, hope someone can help:

```
protected async void LoadChat()
{
    string userid = "123456789";

    var getroom = (await fc.Child("RecordsChat").OnceAsync<GetRoomChats>()).Select(x =>
    new GetRoomChats
    {
        RoomID = x.Key
    }).ToList();

    List<GetRoomChats> listroomuser = new List<GetRoomChats>();

    foreach (var room in getroom)
    {
        string str = null;
        string[] strArr = null;

        string roomget = room.RoomID;
        str = roomget + "_";
        char[] splitchar = { '_' };
        strArr = str.Split(splitchar);

        var getroomuser = strArr.Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var item in getroomuser)
        {
            if (item == userid)
            {
                var roomgetuser = new GetRoomChats()
                {
                    RoomID = roomget
                };
                listroomuser.Add(roomgetuser);
            }
        }                
    }


    if (listroomuser.Count() > 0)
    {
        
        var FirebaseClient = fc
        .Child("RecordsChat")
        .AsObservable<GetRoomChats>()
        .Subscribe(async(dbevent) =>
        {
            //IteamGetRoomChats.Clear();
            foreach (var room in listroomuser)
            {
                if (dbevent.Key == room.RoomID)
                {
                    var lst = (await fc.Child("RecordsChat").Child(dbevent.Key).OrderByKey().LimitToLast(1).OnceAsync<MyDatabaseRecord>()).Select(x =>
                    new MyDatabaseRecord
                    {
                        NameUser = x.Object.NameUser,
                        Content = x.Object.Content,
                        RoomID = x.Object.RoomID,
                        DayCreate = x.Object.DayCreate,
                        AvatarUser = x.Object.AvatarUser,
                        sender_uid = x.Object.sender_uid,
                        receiver_uid = x.Object.receiver_uid,
                        receiver_read = x.Object.receiver_read
                    });

                    bool unread = false;

                    foreach (var i in lst)
                    {
                        if(i.sender_uid == userid)
                        {
                            i.Content = "You: " + i.Content;

                            var customerList = await apiServiceUserinfo.GetCustomersInfo(i.receiver_uid);
                            string nameget = customerList.NameStore;
                            string avatarget = customerList.AvatarStore;

                            i.NameUser = nameget;
                            i.AvatarUser = avatarget;

                            if (i.sender_read == true)
                            {
                                unread = false;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (i.receiver_read == false)
                            {
                                i.BackgroundUser = "#f5f4f4";
                                unread = true;
                            }
                        }

                        var last = new GetRoomChats()
                        {
                            NameLast = i.NameUser,
                            ContentLast = i.Content,
                            RoomID = i.RoomID,
                            DayCreateLast = i.DayCreate,
                            AvatarLast = i.AvatarUser,
                            BackgroundUnread = i.BackgroundUser,
                            DotUnread = unread
                        };

                        IteamGetRoomChats.Add(last);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    BindingContext = this;
}
```

In my example above, it actually gets the data. I try to check in the loop, to get the last content of the message. However, the displayed results are duplicated

[image]

[image]

Looking forward to everyone's help. Thank you!

Comment: each record in the room has an identifier, why aren't you just checking that value to prevent dupes?

Comment: I still don't quite understand your answer :|

Comment: before you add an item to the list, check to see if that item already exists first

Comment: Thanks, I will check it again